# guardar cuotas generadas por javascript en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy haciendo un sistema de credito , y genero cuota

Aqui Genero la cuota y cantidad prestada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui el usuario Ve la cantidad de credito y sus cuotas , el problema como se muestra atravez de javascript pero la idea es que cuando me muestre estos datos 
tambien se guarden en la base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola ramon, para eso te recomiendo una manera segura seria mediante una web api de laravel que incluye tendrías que incorporar los controllers en la api y en javascript realizar una request mediante ajax o  algún mecanismo alternativo.